# Puppet - setting variables

Tags: puppet

I have this in my puppet fle for solr:

```
define solr::core(
$solr_home = "/opt/solr",
$schema_xml = "searchapi_schema.xml",
$solrconfig_xml = "searchapi_solrconfig.xml",
$user = 'jetty'
) { ..
```

I would like to in my node override the variables for $schema_xml and $solrconfig_xml, how do I do that in a nice way?

I tried this:

```
node web02 inherits webbasenode {
  $schema_xml = "apachesolr_schema.xml"
  $solrconfig_xml = "apachesolr_solrconfig.xml"
...
```

But that did not work out.

Comment: Although there is no SO-SF migration path now, this question really belongs on serverfault.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, you need your definition to accept parameters. For example

```
define solr::core ($schema_xml = "searchapi_schema.xml",
$solrconfig_xml = "searchapi_solrconfig.xml"){ .... }
```

In your node, call the definition with the updated parameters. For example

```
node web02 inherits webbasenode {
solr::core {
 schema_xml => "apachesolr_schema.xml",
 solrconfig_xml => "apachesolr_solrconfig.xml"
 }
}
```